# Baking multiple objects with seperate maps at once?

Tags: texture-baking, normal-map

Are there any scripts or add-ons to bake maps for several objects at once?

For example, could you select a list of objects for the low poly and another list for the high poly then export a series of normal and any other wanted maps for each of those objects?

Comment: https://www.blendermarket.com/products/baketool or https://blendermarket.com/products/bake-helper or http://blenderaddonlist.blogspot.pt/2014/09/addon-meltdown-improved-baking-ui.html

Comment: I have never done any baking myself, not usually required for my line of work, so I cannot answer any of those questions. There are usually videos demoing the functionality, if those are not clear enough Blender market has system for questions to the authors, maybe ask there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cycles:

[Bake Tool](https://www.blendermarket.com/products/baketool) offers support for high to low poly baking of multiple objects. Set it up one object (high poly) and target (low poly) per job. Use multiple jobs for each additional set of objects. Bake Tool can also be used for baking multiple maps in BI. (This is helpful for displacement map baking.)

[Meltdown](http://blenderaddonlist.blogspot.pt/2014/09/addon-meltdown-improved-baking-ui.html) also offers similar support.

As of version 2.78c, [Bake Helper](https://blendermarket.com/products/bake-helper) does not support high to low poly baking.